# botframework v4 how to prevent language translator text api translate username on waterfall dialog

Tags: botframework, microsoft-translator

I'm using the demo sample: [BotBuilder Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples)

5.multi-turn-prompt & 
17.multilingual-bot combine as single project.

how can I prevent language translator auto translate the name input by user to other language?

eg:  if my name input in thai, then the bot response will not translate to en/es language.

Comment: Which SDK, C# or JS?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to do this:

If you're using a language that utilizes the Latin alphabet (such as english), you can do a search to see if a userName is included in the turnContext text, and replace it with `<div class="notranslate">USERNAME_HERE</div>` like below (forgive my funny variable names)

[image]

You do have to remember to remove the formatting that might come along, with the following:

[image]

If you're using a language with a dedicated alphabet (for example: Korean), you have to do a detection in the `turnContext.onSendActivities` for the userName, then slice the name out, translate the before and after, and then smoosh it all back together:

[image]

[image]

Comment: method 2 is similiar what i'm doing now, which can place on normal context.sendActivity action, which detected specific pattern in text and skip for that translation, and in the end combine them all and return to user. Thanks alot @JJ_Wailes